# How to make a list with checkbox from an array of object in angular 7 and implement multiple selection and select all feature

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a list in angular using ngFor and each item have a unique id and a checkbox as shown in the diagram but i am unable to figure out how to handle multiple selections and select all and call a function with the array of selected items[image]

Answer (score 0):

change `checkboxList` to your `array list`. and change `ngModel` to your checkbox key

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of checkboxList; let i = index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.checkbox" name="checkbox-{{i}}" />
</tr>
```